# Sed failed to match non whitespace characters with character class

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I want to extract filter rules configured in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`, like `filter = [ "r|/dev/sda|" ]`. I want `sed` to return `"r|/dev/sda|"`. So I have tried the following script:

`echo ' filter = [ "r|/dev/sda|" ] ' | sed -r 's:^\s*filter\s*=\s*\[\s*([^\s]+)\s*\]:\1:g'`

But it didn't work, the script has returned `filter = [ "r|/dev/sda|" ]`.
I've tried a few on line regex tester, the group has been matched correctly.

However, if I replace `[^\s]+` by `.+`, it works.

Doesn't `[^\s]+` mean **more than one non whitespace characters** ?

Any idea please?

Comment: These shorthands cannot be used inside negated bracket expressions. `[^[:space:]]` will work.

Comment: Yes !! thanks you, thank you, thank you very  much, @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: in case you are ok with `grep` : try `grep -oP 'filter.*\K".*?"' inputfile`

Comment: @PS. What does the `\K` stand for ?

Comment: its a `perl` way of saying , ignore everything before `\K`. @vesontio

Comment: @vesontio it's easier do this with \S+ without the [] I wrote it below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acc. to [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html):

> One key syntactic difference is that the backslash is NOT a metacharacter in a POSIX bracket expression. So in POSIX, the regular expression `[\d]` matches a `\` or a `d`.

So you need to replace `[^\s]` with `[^[:space:]]` (*any char other than whitespace*).

[Example](https://ideone.com/5iyI8P):

```
echo ' filter = [ "r|/dev/sda|" ] ' | sed -E 's:^\s*filter\s*=\s*\[\s*([^[:space:]]+)\s*\]:\1:g'
```

Output: `"r|/dev/sda|"`

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively easier and  shorter than `[^[:space:]]`  you can do with `\S+` without using brackets `[]`

`\S` means **non** whitespace char

```
echo ' filter = [ "r|/dev/sda|" ] ' | sed -r 's:^\s*filter\s*=\s*\[\s*(\S+)\s*\]:\1:g'
```

https://ideone.com/PxDX1Q

Answer (score 1):

In case  grep solution is acceptable :

```
grep -oP 'filter.*\K".*?"' inputfile
```